# Access blob by index in Pycaffe

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I can access blobs in a network using their name.
For example:

```
net.blobs['data'].data.shape
```

returns the shape of the above layer.
Is there a way to access the layer by it's index?  I tried the following:

```
net.blobs[1].data.shape
```

but I get an uninformative python exception

> ```
> KeyError: 1
> ```

I need to access it in the above-mentioned manner since at run-time, I don't have the name of the layer I want to access.
Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net.blobs` is an [Ordered Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) object, therefore you cannot access its items via numerical index, you need to use string keys.

You can get a list of the available keys by `net.blobs.keys()`, and you can access blobs using:

```
net.blobs[net.blobs.keys()[1]].data.shape
```

But you should be careful doing so: caffe may introduce auxiliary blobs in your model (specifically, `split` layers when one `"top"` is fed as `"bottom"` to several layers).

Comment: Another option would be using `net.blobs.keys()` instead of `net._blob_names`.

Comment: @dorverbin indeed, these two lists are identical

Comment: @Shai and dorverbin Thank you both for the answers!